# what are backend and frontend in traefik.toml

Tags: configuration, config, configuration-files, traefik

While reading the Documents of Traefik I was confused when I face the configuration skeleton that was mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/file/):

traefik.toml:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
    # ...
  [entryPoints.https]
    # ...

[file]

# rules
[backends]
  [backends.backend1]
    # ...
  [backends.backend2]
    # ...

[frontends]
  [frontends.frontend1]
  # ...
  [frontends.frontend2]
  # ...
  [frontends.frontend3]
  # ...

# HTTPS certificate
[[tls]]
  # ...

[[tls]]
  # ...
```

what is the reason behind dividing rule section in the configuration file into two different sub-sections as `backend` and `frontend`?

Answer (score 1):

Without dividing it into backend and frontend, i would not have been able to connect multiple services to the same backend and as such, have load-balancing even though i configured multiple services.

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  minio1:
    image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2018-11-30T03-56-59Z
    hostname: minio1
    volumes:
      - minio1-data:/export
    ports:
      - target: 9000
        mode: host
    networks:
      - minio_distributed
      - webgateway
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        delay: 10s
        max_attempts: 10
        window: 60s
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.docker.network=webgateway
        - traefik.backend=minio
        - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:minio.mycooldomain.com
        - traefik.port=9000
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.minio1==true
    command: server http://minio1/export http://minio2/export http://minio3/export http://minio4/export
    secrets:
      - secret_key
      - access_key

  minio2:
    image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2018-11-30T03-56-59Z
    hostname: minio2
    volumes:
      - minio2-data:/export
    ports:
      - target: 9000
        mode: host
    networks:
      - minio_distributed
      - webgateway
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        delay: 10s
        max_attempts: 10
        window: 60s
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.docker.network=webgateway
        - traefik.backend=minio
        - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:minio.mycooldomain.com
        - traefik.port=9000
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.minio2==true
    command: server http://minio1/export http://minio2/export http://minio3/export http://minio4/export
    secrets:
      - secret_key
      - access_key

volumes:
  minio1-data:
  minio2-data:
  minio3-data:
  minio4-data:

networks:
  minio_distributed:
    driver: overlay
  webgateway:
    external: true

secrets:
  secret_key:
    external: true
  access_key:
    external: true
```

thats an example from me, where the service "minio1" and "minio2" are reachable through the same domain. normally as soon as i have different services, each gets its own backend automatically and i would have had to give each service its own domain and only a single service where i scale the number up, these additional containers would be reachable on the same domain.

Hope i was able to explain it a bit with my own experience. :)
Note that i even have 4 minio services, i just cut it to shorten the config

Comment: what I understand from your example is that the `frontend` side is the public side that everybody can access the service through that, and after getting the request from that terminal Traefik will parse the request and determines how to treat them according to the predefined rules in the Configuration file, am I right?

Comment: basicly yes. i think the documentation of traefik does explain it nicely already though.
https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#frontends


**A frontend consists of a set of rules that determine how incoming requests are forwarded from an entrypoint to a backend.**

https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#backends
**A backend is responsible to load-balance the traffic coming from one or more frontends to a set of http servers.**

Comment: Great, that's just what I needed, I don't know how to Mark your comment as the answer of the question, If we can't mark this comment as the answer please send it as an Answer to be able to do so.